# Macro-driven conditional first argument to a function

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have an API that behaves along the following lines:

```c
#ifdef MYLIB_SINGLETON
  void* mylib_malloc(size_t size);
  void mylib_free(void* ptr);
  void mylib_log(int level, const char* msg, ...);
#else
  void* mylib_malloc(void* ctx, size_t size);
  void mylib_free(void* ctx, void* ptr);
  void mylib_log(void* ctx, int level, const char* msg, ...);
#endif
```

I want to remove the duplication. In C++, I would use a simple-ish template, but this is a C header. My options appear to be:

- Macros.
- Generate the header from a spec file as part of the build process.
- Deal with it. Until this multiplexes 4-ways or more, it's not that fragile.

As far as macros go. The best I could do is the following, but I'm far from comfortable enough with macros to feel confident that it's as clean as it can get.

```c
#ifdef MYLIB_SINGLETON
  #define MYLIB_FUNC_ARGS(...) ##__VA_ARGS__
#else
  #define MYLIB_FUNC_ARGS(...) void* ctx, ##__VA_ARGS__
#endif

void* mylib_malloc( MYLIB_FUNC_ARGS(size_t size) );
void mylib_free( MYLIB_FUNC_ARGS(void* free) );
void mylib_log( MYLIB_FUNC_ARGS(const char* msg, ...) );
```

It's not completely terrible, but not quite good enough to my eyes.

**Edit:** to clarify, it's not the only thing I came up with, just what I feel is the best. In particular the following works, but I don't like them for the stated reasons

```
// It looks like MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX alters the size parameter, instead of being a parameter in its own right.
void* mylib_malloc(MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX size_t size);

// Very confusing at a glance.
void* MYLIB_FUNC(mylib_malloc, size_t size);
```

I'd rather have a solution that would be more intuitive to read for users of the library. Something along the following lines would be nice. As far as I know, it's not possible, though.

```c
void* mylib_malloc(MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX, size_t size);
void mylib_free(MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX, void* free);
void mylib_log(MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX, const char* msg, ...);
```

Is there some macro wizardry possible, or just something obvious I'm not seeing, that would allow me to provide both interfaces in one go while still intuitively looking like functions for a would-be user of the library? Alternatively, an authoritative "Nope, that's as good as you are going to get" answer would let me stop worrying about this.

Comment: It is very much possible, just lose the comma after MYLIB_MAYBE_CTX.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, obviously, I really should have mentionned that it was my first immediate solution. I consider it worse than what I landed on because it's *really* unintuitive to read. I've amended the question.

Comment: In the end of the day it is a question of personal aesthetic preference. Would you prefer to look at `void* mylib_malloc(MAYBE_CTX)(size_t size);`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Not in particular, but if such a syntax was possible, then `void* MYLIB_FUNC(mylib_malloc)(size_t size);` should be as well, and that would be much better.

Comment: It is possible, but not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible syntax

```
#ifdef MYLIB_SINGLETON
      #define MYLIB_ARGS(...) (__VA_ARGS__)
#else
      #define MYLIB_ARGS(...) (void *ctx, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

#define MYLIB_FUNC(x) x MYLIB_ARGS

void* MYLIB_FUNC(mylib_malloc)(size_t size);
void MYLIB_FUNC(mylib_free)(void* free);
void MYLIB_FUNC(mylib_log)(const char* msg, ...);
```

Comment: Nice.  I have some JNI code that might benefit from that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have simplified it a bit and it is no longer so repulsive...

Comment: Indeed, even better.

Comment: To make sure I understand what's going on here. `MYLIB_FUNC` expands to a functional macro to which the original argument list becomes an invocation of. Is this correct?

Comment: @Frank exactly.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That's fascinating. For some reason, I always though that macros using other macros recursed "internally". That it recurses on the expanded macro alongside the rest of the code opens up a world of possibilities. Thank you.